# Showing that $\dim( H \cap K) \leq \dim(H)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

In the text "Linear Algebra and it's Applications" by David C Lay, Stevan R Lay and Judi J McDonald I'm inquiring if my solution for the following problem is correct ?

$\textbf{Problem}$

Prove that,

$$\dim( H \cap K) \leq \dim(H)$$

$\text{Solution}$

To establish the inequality introduce respectively,

$$H=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}h_{11} & h_{12} & \cdots & h_{1 n} \\ a_{21} & h_{22} & \cdots & h_{2 n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ h_{m 1} & h_{m 2} & \cdots & h_{m n}\end{array}\right], K=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}k_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & k_{1 n} \\ k_{21} & k_{22} & \cdots & k_{2 n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ k_{m 1} & k_{m 2} & \cdots & k_{m n}\end{array}\right]$$

Putting the icing on the cake, and lastly via [Theorem (11)](http://mathb.in/44363) we see that,

$$\dim( H \cap K) \leq \dim(H) = \dim \Bigg( \left[\begin{array}{cccc}h_{11} & h_{12} & \cdots & h_{1 n} \\ a_{21} & h_{22} & \cdots & h_{2 n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ h_{m 1} & h_{m 2} & \cdots & h_{m n}\end{array}\right] \bigcap \left[\begin{array}{cccc}k_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & k_{1 n} \\ k_{21} & k_{22} & \cdots & k_{2 n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ k_{m 1} & k_{m 2} & \cdots & k_{m n}\end{array}\right] \Bigg) \leq \dim \Bigg(\left[\begin{array}{cccc}h_{11} & h_{12} & \cdots & h_{1 n} \\ a_{21} & h_{22} & \cdots & h_{2 n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ h_{m 1} & h_{m 2} & \cdots & h_{m n}\end{array}\right] \Bigg)$$

$$  \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,    = \dim \Big( \sum h_{i}a_{i} \, \bigcap \, \, \sum k_{i}a_{i} \Big) \leq \dim \Big( \sum h_{i}a_{i} \Big)$$

$$ \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! =  p \leq \dim \Big( \sum h_{i}a_{i} \Big). $$

QED.

Comment: You might be working too hard. One quicker way to prove this is to observe that $H\cap K$ is a subspace of $H$, and therefore it follows immediately that $\dim H\cap K\leq \dim H$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow yeah I figured it's easy to note that $H\cap K$ is indeed a subspace of $H$ since it satisfies subspace axioms so by Theorem (11)  I could see how the conclusion follows

Comment: $H$ and $K$ are subspaces and matrices at the same time?!

Comment: What is $V$ in your first line of the solution? Why are there $a_{21}$ and $a_{12}$ in $H$ and $K$, are those typos? Presumably $H$ and $K$ are linear spans of some vectors, not matrices. It doesn't make sense to take the intersection of two matrices, or later on, two vectors.

Comment: @RandyMarsh yes those are typo's on my part now for the proof my intention was to introduce $H$ and $K$ as arbitrary matrices but eventually getting the spanning set of $H$ and $K$ respectively the carry on from there via Theorem (11). I apologize for the error i'll eventually get around to rewriting the proof so things are a bit more clear and less obtuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $H$ and $K$ are subspaces of an ambient vector space $V$. By the Theorem you linked [Theorem (11)], since $H\cap K$ is a subspace of $H$, it follows that $\dim H\cap K\le \dim H$.

You don't need to appeal to bases at all once you know the theorem you linked.

Comment: Yeah that is fair I essentially did it the long way around because I noticed in the book there are some theorems that automate the process of constructing the bases for given space/subspace so I wanted to do it manually to get an appreciation for results